# How to display html code normally?

Tags: html, formatting

I want to display my html code as it write in edited format.

Here is my edited html code.
[image]

It display as following after publishing it.
[image]

How to make it displayed as the following?

[image]

Comment: You might find these resources helpful:    http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask  and  https://make.wordpress.org/support/user-manual/content/editors/visual-editor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have in the  main editor, 2 modes:

- visual tab
- Text tab

I think you have published your post (or page) under "Text" mode.

What you have to do is **to cut all the html code** in "Text" mode tab. Then you have to set the editor in "Visual" mode tab, and to paste your code.

Your code will be displayed like you want to.

Best, now what you can do (in "Text" editor mode), is to use the html `<code>` tag before and a html `</code>` tag after...

Regards

Comment: I found a good method to install Wp-syntax plugin to do the job.

Comment: For this purpose **Wp-syntax** is the must have. I have just discover it. thanks